# How to dedupe contacts in email sends when using Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I'm setting up a customer journey where an email is being sent to some of our new customers.  When manually sending an email, there's a 'deduplicate subscribers' checkbox you can click.  This checkbox does not exist when configuring emails in Journey Builder.

Is there a way to ensure email sends via Journey Builder are deduplicated?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to help you on this query. In JB we have a feature of contact entry mode where we can specify is the contact can enter a journey single time or multiple times.
In your scenario when there is duplicate email ids are present, once a contact is injected the contacts with duplicate email ids will be barred from entering the journey.
So de-duping happens at the time of entering the journey itself.

[image]